# Saving a matrix of standard errors after the tab command with survey weights

Tags: stata

I'm using this estimation command:
svy brr, mse: tab Variable1, se percent format (%9.6f)

I was able to save the estimates using:
matrix est = e(Prop)

Is there a similar command that I can use to save my standard errors in a matrix?

I've tried several codes that haven't worked, including:

matrix se = e(se)